# Facebook messages causing the Facebook app on my iPad to crash

Tags: ipad, ios, crash, facebook

I have an iPad mini, updated to iOS 6. I can use my Facebook app well in every department apart from messages. In both the top display and side display, when I click on the messages option the Facebook app will crash. I have tried uninstalling the app, restarting, installing and restarting, but nothing improves or changes. Also I have tried the proper restart by holding down both the top lock/unlock button and home button but that has not worked either.

Is there anything else I can do to fix this crashing problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if this is a bug that needs to be fixed with a new release of e program, but you could follow this path and try reinstalling the older version of the app from a computer and or computer backup.

[What can we do now that Facebook iPad app crashes on launch after update?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75717/what-can-we-do-now-that-facebook-ipad-app-crashes-on-launch-after-update)