# Sending messages over Facebook causes app to crash

Tags: crash, facebook

Every time I try to message a friend of mine on Facebook, the app shuts down. This does not happen with other friends.

Comment: did you look at: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76293/facebook-messages-causing-the-facebook-app-on-my-ipad-to-crash?rq=1 ?

Comment: What browser do you use ?

Comment: This is on my iPad. It is Safari, but it only happens with 1 friend.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with the install of your app. Did you have consistent internet access when the app was updated or installed? If so, you should uninstall and reinstall the app.

Comment: Install of what? Please be more specific.

Comment: The internet access is not the problem. I went ahead and did a brand new download of the app as well. Why would this happen with just 1 of my friends and not the rest?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that you meant only one friend! Does it still not work?

Comment: Still not working for he 1 friend. Weird.

Comment: Well, this must be a Facebook-side issue. You should report a bug! :) https://www.facebook.com/help/www/326603310765065